# Adding characters to string

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I am currently trying to build a very basic serial shell with my arduino.

I am able to get an output from the device using Serial.read() and can get the character it has outputted, but I cannot work out how to then add that character to a longer to form the full command.

I tried the logical thing but it doesn't work:

```
char Command[];

void loop(){
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    int clinput = Serial.read();
    Command = Command + char(clinput);
}
```

Can anybody help? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use std::string if you can. If you can't :

```
snprintf(Command, sizeof(Command), "%s%c", Command, clinput);
```

or (remeber to check that Command does not grow too much...)

```
size_t len = strlen(Command);
Command[len] = clinput;
Command[len + 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: command doesnt point at anything, sizeof (command) = 4 (or maybe 2 on arduino)

Comment: Thanks so much, I've literally spent a day googling :D

Answer (score 3):

You have to write character by character into an array.
For example like this:

```
#define MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH 20

char Command[MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH];
int commandLength;    

void loop(){
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    int clinput = Serial.read();
    if (commandLength < MAX_COMMAND_LENGTH) {
      Command[commandLength++] = (char)clinput;
    }
}
```

BTW: This is not complete. E.g. commandLength has to be initialized with 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate enough space in `command` hold the longest commmand 
and then write characters into it as the come in.  When you run out of characters,
you null terminate the command and then return.

```
char Command[MAX_COMMAND_CHARS];

void loop() {
  int ix = 0; 
  // uncomment this to append to the Command buffer
  //ix = strlen(Command);

  while(ix < MAX_COMMAND_CHARS-1 && Serial.available() > 0) {
     Command[ix] = Serial.read();
     ++ix;
  }

  Command[ix] = 0; // null terminate the command
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::ostringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/) with [std::string](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string loop()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    while ( Serial.available() > 0 ){
        oss << static_cast<char>(Serial.read());
    }
    return oss.str();
}
```

You can also concatenate multiple instances of std::string with operator+.

Answer (score 0):

Since its also tagged C,

```
char *command = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXLENGTH);
*command = '\0';

void loop(){
  char clinput[2] = {}; //for nullifying the array
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    clinput[0] = (char)Serial.read();
    strcat(command, clinput);
}
```

Comment: strcat takes a char* as its second arg

Answer (score -1):

```
 char command[MAX_COMMAND];
 void loop(){
     char *p = command;
    if(Serial.available() > 0){
      int clinput = Serial.read();
    command[p++] = (char)clinput;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Should check for buffer overflow though.

Comment: Almost certainly a seg fault if it even compiles. p is a pointer to char, not an index into a char array.

Comment: @simon are you serious? char * points perfectly happily to char array. Hopefully you will downvoted the accepted answer since that writes to an unitilaized pointer

Comment: Simon is probably serious, since he is correct. Look at your last line. I doubt you meant to index the command array with a pointer. Perhaps you meant *p++ = (char)clinput;